# Aligning header menu in the center

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with centrally aligning the whole menu container marked with yellow color in the [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/rgf1d2).

`"margin: auto"` just does not work for some reason which I don't yet understand. The menu container still floats in the left.

I will much appreciate your help.

Please see the full markup and CSS below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008686, #024848);
}

.brand-logo {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-container {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  margin: auto;
}

.brand-logo,
.menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f8f143;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.menu-icon {
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu-name-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-name {
  font-family: Wendy One;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #f8f143;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-icon,
.menu-name-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.brand-logo,
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">

    <a href=""><img src="buff.png" class="brand-logo"></img></a>

    <div class="menu-container">
        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 125px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Sports Betting Guides</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 110px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Horse Racing Guides</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 55px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Casino Guides</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 60px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Betting Tools</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 80px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Betting Strategies</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 60px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">Betting Tips</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <img src="android.png" class="menu-icon"></img>
            <div class="menu-name-container" style="width: 55px">
                <a href="" class="menu-name">News Corner</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

To align the menu in the center of the *entire* row, regardless of the logo width, you would need to absolutely position it, with the `.menu-container` as a relative container.

```
.header-container {
  …
  position: relative;
}

.menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but it takes the right edge of the brand logo as a point for allignment. How can I centrally anign using the the entire width of the header.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rgjrwh - here is what I have now

`.header-container{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008686, #024848);
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brand-logo{
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-container{
    width: fit-content;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}`

Answer (score 1):

@Andy, I did sone edit in the code you suggested and it worked, please see it below:

```
.header-container{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008686, #024848);
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brand-logo{
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-container{
    width: fit-content;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Thanks very much for your help, you gave me the idea which I did not know :)

But now when I am hovering a menu element, the one that I am hovering stays at the same position, the others go down by 10px.
I would like the hoverable element to go up and others stay in the same position.

Please see the code:

```
.header-container{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008686, #024848);
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brand-logo{
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.menu-container{
    width: fit-content;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.brand-logo, .menu-container{
    display: inline-block;                                           
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.menu-item{
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-left: 30px;

}

.menu-item:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F8F143;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;      
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```